# How to do non blocking usb serial input in circuit python?

Tags: python, usb, adafruit-circuitpython

I am trying to interface a micropython board with python on my computer using serial read and write, however I can't find a way to read usb serial data in micropython that is non-blocking.

Basicly I want to call the input function without requiring an input to move on. (something like https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython/pull/1186 but for usb)

I have tried using [tasko](https://github.com/WarriorOfWire/tasko), uselect (it failed to import the library and I can't find a download), and await functions. I'm not sure it there is a way to do this, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CircuitPython there's [supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shared-bindings/supervisor/index.html#supervisor.Runtime.serial_bytes_available) which may provide the building block for what you want to do.

This is discussed on [Adafruit Forums: Receive commands from the computer via USB](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=146394&hilit=supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available).

Comment: BTW, sending binary data to CircuitPython over serial console might be problematic, [GH: adafruit/circuitpython 'getch()' #231](https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython/issues/231) mentions this at the end with control-c and control-d (that one seems odd) being picked up by REPL and a prospective feature to improve this. There might be a workaround, there's mention of using the not-supported-in-CircuitPython `micropython.kbd_Intr()` in [Adafruit Forums: replace ctrl-c, e.g. by ctrl-g](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=173071&p=847223&hilit=disable+KeyboardInterrupt+ctrl-c).

Answer (score 1):

based on the relative new added [`usb_cdc` buildin](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shared-bindings/usb_cdc/index.html) (>= 7.0.0) you can do something like this:

```py
def read_serial(serial):
    available = serial.in_waiting
    while available:
        raw = serial.read(available)
        text = raw.decode("utf-8")
        available = serial.in_waiting
    return text

# main
buffer = ""
serial = usb_cdc.console
while True:
    buffer += read_serial(serial)
    if buffer.endswith("\n"):
        # strip line end
        input_line = buffer[:-1]
        # clear buffer
        buffer = ""
        # handle input
        handle_your_input(input_line)

    do_your_other_stuff()
```

this is a very simple example.
the line-end handling could get very complex if you want to support [*universal line ends*](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) and multiple commands send at once...

i have created a library based on this: [CircuitPython_nonblocking_serialinput](https://github.com/s-light/CircuitPython_nonblocking_serialinput)