# CircuitPython supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available still True after reading

Tags: python, stdin, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm working on a project involving a Node website and an Adafruit 8x8 button matrix
using the Feather M4 Express microcontroller and CircuitPython. I am trying to sort
out clean serial communication between the website and the button grid via USB.

This is the current loop I have on the microcontroller, which is supposed to just check
for serial input, and print it if it exists.

```
while True:
    # the trellis can only be read every 17 millisecons or so
    trellis.sync()

    if supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available:
        data = input()
        print(data)

    time.sleep(0.02)
```

This works for the first iteration. The problem is, after the first `input()` call,
`supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available` isn't being reset to False.
Hence, in the second iteration, the microcontroller hangs at `input()` until I send it
something over serial. This happens for every following iteration.

How can I make sure `supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available` will be set back to False after I read the input?

Answer (score 1):

[supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shared-bindings/supervisor/index.html#supervisor.Runtime.serial_bytes_available) is giving you the *number* of bytes to read as an `int` but can still be used as a boolean value with zero equating to `False`. It will be dependent on what data you are sending as to whether `input()` reads all of that data, i.e. data like `"a line\na partial line"` will hang on the second line. You can read any data with `sys.stdin.read()` but you have to do a little extra work to coalesce/parse that data. Some caution on end of line characters is also required, you may find sequences like `CRLF` in data.

Depending on what you are sending you may hit some issues with control characters. This can be disabled for the problematic Control-C (`0x03` causing `KeyboardInterrupt`) with use [micropython.kbd_intr()](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/library/micropython.html?highlight=kbd_intr#micropython.kbd_intr) of according to [Adafruit Forums: replace ctrl-c, e.g. by ctrl-g](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=173071&p=847402&hilit=kbd_intr#p847402)

There's some overlap here with the question/answer in [How to do non blocking usb serial input in circuit python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65647986/how-to-do-non-blocking-usb-serial-input-in-circuit-python)